# Porting VS2005 project to VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

i need to port a VS2005 Project (.NET2) to a VS2008 (.NET3.5) (or to VS2010 .NET4 not yet defined).

The project is composed by:

- resources and configuration files (VS project files, like: .settings
  .vbproj .myapp .config .xconfig .Designer.vb);
- a lot of VB codes;
- xsc, xsd, xss and xsx files;
- a lot of Crystal reports for VS2005;
- graphical resources.

The application take data in order to generate reports from more DB SQL Server 2005 istances.

What is the best way to approach to a migration activity?

Is there an internal migration tool?
If yes, what's the best practice to use it?
Which kind of files will be automatically ported to the new VS version?

Thanks in advance for all the provided information

Answer (score 0):

It should be backward compatible.

Therefore, you should be able to simply open the project in the target version of Visual Studio and perform a conversion if required (for the project files). I suggest taking a backup first however, just in case.

Then compile test and test some more.

Should be fine.

Comment: I hope, and what about the Crystal Report for VS2005, are also compatibile with VS2008 or VS2010?
Thanks